# Reuse method with different model class - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I've working in a project and I noticed have many same methods for differents models:

```
Class1::where('id', $id)
      ->update($request->except('_token'));

Class2::where('id', $id)
      ->update($request->except('_token'));

Class3::where('id', $id)
      ->update($request->except('_token'));
```

So I think is so repetitive have those methods in each class.
Is there any way to make a generic method and use it in my controller, like this?

```
AnyClass::genericMethod($id);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could possibly make use of Laravel Macros to register such method? Would need to make sure if Eloquent Models allow same macro registration as Collections, Relations and such (or add the trait yourself to an extended base Model class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use trait for methods like this:

```
trait SomeTrait
{
    public function genericMethod($id)
    {
        return $this->where('id', $id)->update(request()->except('_token'));
    }
}
```

And add it to as many models as you like:

```
class Class3 extends Model
{
    use SomeTrait;
```

Comment: Traits shouldn't rely on methods or properties outside of the trait. `where()` is a method on `Model`, not the trait.

Comment: @JRLambert well, look into traits Laravel uses. For example, `SoftDeletes`.

Comment: When I do that, I got this error: Non-static method App\Class3::genericMethod() should not be called statically

Comment: @SundayGirl if you want to use it as a static method, add `static` to the method definition like `public static function` and change `$this` to `self::`

Comment: But if I do that, I got this new error: Using $this when not in object context